# Find maximum and minimum values of the function in the region

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

I have $z = -x^2-2x-y^2+6y+8$ and region $D = (x+1)^2 + (y-3)^2 \le 1.$
Here is what I have

```
1)Finding stationary point:
```

$\frac{\partial z} {\partial x} = -2x-2=0; x=-1;\\
\frac {\partial z} {\partial y} = -2y+6=0; y=3;$ 
Getting $M_0(-1;3) \in D$ 
$\frac {\partial^2z} {\partial x^2} = -2; \frac {\partial^2z} {\partial y^2} = -2;\frac {\partial^2z} {\partial x \partial y} = 0;$ (conditions of an extremum are met) 
Verifying $AC - B^2 > 0$, where $A = -2, C = -2$ and $B = 0$: 
$-2\cdot(-2)-0>0$ (true). And $A < 0$ therefore it's a maximum point. 
$z_{max}= z(-1;3) = -1+2-9+18+8 = $ **18**

```
2)We explore the region border - Here is where my problem is.
```

I've used 2 ways to find critical points:
**1)** separate $y$ or $y^2$ and then put in original expression and **2)** use the Lagrange formula.
When I'm trying to get $y$ or $(y-3)^2$ or $y^2$ and put it back into original expression I'm getting situation when all the $x$ variables are reduced (e.g. $z=-x^2-2x-y^2+6y+8 = -x^2-2x-(y-3)^2+9+8;\\
(y-3)^2 = 1-(x+1)^2;\\
z = -x^2-2x-1-(x-1)^2+17=17$ 
When using Lagrange formula I'm getting $x$ and $y$ without $\lambda$:
 $x=-2; y=3$
So it gives me point $M_1(-2;3)$. But I'm not sure whether I do everything correctly. Can you help me with this? Maybe I'm wrong with first way or with second? Or I'm wrong at all? The task looks simple. 
Thanks in advance to all!

Comment: Why? It belongs to border of circle (Center point is (-1;3) and $R$ = 1)

Comment: Yes, $M_1 \in D$.  Another way to cross check is to note $z = 18-(x+1)^2 - (y-3)^2$ which has an obvious max.

Comment: Yes, max is where $(x+1)^2 = 0$ and $(y-3)^2=0$, in $M_0(-1;3)$. But, how can I find the minimum point?

Comment: Anywhere on the border, $z = 17$ identically which is what you effectively got too.  That gives you the minimum point(s) in this case as there are no other critical points.  Alternately the quadratic is concave, so minima is on the boundary...

Comment: Yes, with Lagrange formula I've got $z=17$ minimum. I just wasn't sure whether I'm right. So, only 2 critical points that I can find? That's correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easier way of doing this is realizing the following:
$$-x^2-2x-y^2+6y+8=-(x+1)^2-(y-3)^2+18$$

So, of course $(-1,3)$ is a local maximum. In fact, we can say with certainty that it is a global maximum, since $ (x+1)^2+(y-3)^2 \geq 0$

The minimum value of $f(x,y)$ on $D$ must be $17$, since for all $(x_0, y_0)$ in $D$, $(x_0+1)^2+(y_0-3)^2\leq1$, implying the following: 
$$f(x_0,y_0)=-(x_0+1)^2-(y_0-3)^2+18\geq-1+18=17$$

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, but only one elaboration: what is $x_0$ and $y_0$ in digits?

Comment: **UPD:** Understood what happens in your last line, thanks, no need to answer the question above :)